# JavaScript, Manipulating HTML 'style' using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a bowling game and I have created buttons 0-10.

When I bowl a 7, for example, I'd like only buttons 0-3 to be available. Then once one of these (0-3) has been clicked, all the (0-10) buttons should be visible again.

Have been trying to manipulate:

```
style="display: inline;"
```

To

```
style="display: none;"
```

Have tried using `.toggleClass` and `.removeClass` but since I'm not manipulating these via the css, not sure of my options.

Comment: That's CSS, not a class. If you created a "hidden"class that applied `display: none`, then toggled that class it would work.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question since I don't bowl, but it looks like jQuery's hide() and show() functions will be useful to you

Comment: Using `$("#your-button").hide()` sets the style to `style="display: none;"`. Similarly, `$("#your-button").show()` removes that style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can:

```
$('element').css('display', 'none|block');
```

With pure Javascript you can:

```
document.querySelector('element').style.display = 'none|block';
```

Note that in jQuery you can use `hide()` and `show()` or to modify directly the `css` value within any value you want, the difference is that `hide()` is equivalent to `display: none` and `show()` could be equivalent to `display: block`, if you'd like to set properties like `inline`, `inline-block`, `flex`, `table`, etc. you should use the jQuery `element.css`.

Check this playground:

```js
let el = $('.hallo');
$('.hide').click(function() {
  el.hide();
});
$('.show').click(function() {
  el.show();
});
$('.css').click(function() {
  el.css('display', $('.prop').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="hallo">Hallo</h1>

Set the display value <input type="text" name="prop" class="prop">

<br><br>

<button class="hide" type="submit">jQuery hide()</button>
<button class="show" type="submit">jQuery show()</button>
<button class="css"  type="submit">jQuery css()</button>
```

Comment: Show doesn't set `display: block`. It is actually context-sensitive. Example: paste in the browser console: `$("<span>").show()[0]` and `$("<div>").show()[0]`. Notice the first outputs `<span style="display: inline;"></span>` and the second `<div style="display: block;"></div>`.

Comment: That's relative @acdcjunior, "_... This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline._"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I think this last statement of yours fits what I meant by "context-sensitive", no?